# Setting xticks and yticks for scatter plot matrix with pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I'm using Pandas to create a scatterplot matrix visualization. But I only want to show three ticks for the x axis and y axis. I want to show the ticks at [0.0, 0.5, 0.1] because I have so many variables in the matrix.

Here's my code:

```
X = np.random.uniform(size=(10,100))
X = X.T
df = pd.DataFrame(X)
scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, diagonal='kde')
pylab.xticks([0.0, 0.5, 1.0], [0.0, 0.5, 1.0])
pylab.yticks([0.0, 0.5, 1.0], [0.0, 0.5, 1.0])
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23010837/625914) solution and just modify it to `ax.set_xticks([0, .5, 1])` inside the loops and similarly for the `yticks`

Comment: @alextwain ping me if you do not agree that this is a duplicate.